# Error exporting HTML table to Excel using javascript, on server only

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javascript code that  download html table into excel sheet. It works fine in my localhost. But when I upload it to the live server it give this error. And this error is because, in javascript code there is a line

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
```

But this line never gives error in my localhost and the result is just fine. 
Could you help me please. 
Thank you...

Comment: Sounds like you have short tags enabled on your live server.

Comment: Ahh, may be. How can I stop short tag with php code?

Comment: Do you not have access to your php.ini?

Comment: Add short_open_tag=Off to your php.ini file

Comment: Thanks. Edited the php.ini file and worked.. You guys should have posted as answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
```

to

`<php mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet" ?>`